# React component doesn't re-render on first prop-change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, arraylist

I am new to React and I am trying to build a hangman game.
At the moment I am using a hardcoded list of words that the program can choose from. So far everything worked great, but now I am trying to reset the game and the react component that should rerender upon one click only re-renders after two clicks on the reset button and I don't know why

these are the states that I am using :

```
function App() {
  const [numberInList, setNumberInList] = useState(0)
  const randomWordsList = ["comfort", "calm", "relax", "coffee", "cozy"];
  const [generatedWord, setGeneratedWord] = useState(
    randomWordsList[numberInList]
  );
const [generatedWordLetters, setGeneratedWordLetters] = useState(
    randomWordsList[numberInList].split("").map((letter) => {
      return { letter: letter.toUpperCase(), matched: false };
    })
  );
```

```
function resetGame(){
    
    setNumberInList(prev => prev + 1)

    setGeneratedWord(randomWordsList[numberInList])

    setGeneratedWordLetters(
      generatedWord.split("").map((letter) => {
        return { letter: letter.toUpperCase(), matched: false };
      })
    );

    setFalseTries(0)
  }
```

this is the reset function I am using
within teh function every state gets updated correctly apart from the generatedWordLetters state, which only gets updated upon clicking the reset button two times.

I can't seem to solve this problem on my own, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please check useEffect on React. You can use boolean flag as state, put the useEffect parameters like below

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    // here your code works
},[flag])
```

flag is your boolean state when it changes on reset function, your component re render

Comment: And I put the function in the useeffect?

Comment: Actually no need, you might need to reverse flag boolean.

Comment: can you give me an example of how to implement useeffect with my code? should I put something inside the useEffect or not?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/live/94ab6819c72 please take a look on this.
there are few adjustments
--- no need numberInList state, you would apply Math.random built in func
--- boolean flag for useEffect

Comment: can I just send you the repository on github?

Comment: I hope this path helps you, please feel free to ask anything you want

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt work, because I am working with more than 1 component

Comment: please send your repo

Comment: https://github.com/mischulz14/Hangman-in-React